# Is there any 1 byte ic?

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, ram

I need a system where 1 transistor = 1 bit. with a capcitor for each bit as ram, this would become space consuming, is there an ic that will act like 1 byte ram?

Comment: Why don't you explain what you are attempting to do.  We might be better able to help you.

Comment: @DwayneReid https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NLuU6SgQmPe4SskaYQMCvzXQdDrN4jTu24V9kfKRCWA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's called a "register".

Comment: @VillaCaleb  Your write-up in the Google docs is short enough to be included into the question itself.  That way, the question will be self-contained.

Answer (score 4):

An octal latch, like a 74HC373, is a 1 byte memory.

Answer (score 0):

DRAMs (Dynamic Random Access Memories) usually work as the question describes, i.e. they contain an array of charge storage cells consisting of one capacitor and transistor per data bit. Far from consuming much space, these cells are routinely integrated in *thousands* on a silicon chip. A Wikipedia article shows how far DRAM technology has developed http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory. While nobody makes a DRAM that stores only 8 bits, you can short together all the address input pins of virtually any DRAM that has a byte-wide output to reduce it to a single-address 8-bit memory; alternatively short together all but two of the address pins and ignore all the output pins except one. This way uses the DRAM as a bit-wide memory that addresses of one of eight bits by means of 3 address inputs.